# Given $2$ integers $a,b$ which sum to a prime, is it possible to find a new integer $x$, so that $a+ bx$ is NOT prime?

Tags: prime-numbers

We start with $2$ unknown integers $a,b$.
It is known that the sum of $a$ and $b$ is prime and $a$ is not negativ and $b$ is greater than $0$.

$a+b$ is prime, where $a \ge 0, b > 0$

Is it possible to find a non negativ integer $x$
depending on $a$ and $b$, so that $a + x\cdot b$ is NOT prime ?

Comment: Have you had any thoughts yourself? Have you tried any examples?

Comment: I think you can settle this yourself if you think a bit.

Comment: $a+ab$ is divisible by $a$

Comment: ah yes, of course, ty

Comment: If $a=0, x=2$ works. If $a>1$ then $x=a$ works. So you just need $a=1.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given any positive integer $k,$  if $x=1+ (a+b)k,$ then $$\begin{align}a+bx&=a+b(1+(a+b)k)\\&=a+b+b(a+b)k\\&=(a+b)(1+bk).\end{align}$$

This gives infinitely many $x$ so that $a+bx$ is not prime and, specifically, divisible by $a+b.$

This can be written in terms of congruence:

$$x\equiv 1\pmod {a+b}\implies \\a+bx\equiv 0\pmod {a+b}$$

In particular, when $x>1,$ $a+bx>a+b$ and is divisible by $a+b.$

---

More generally, if $p(x)$ is a non-constant  integer polynomial with non-negative coefficients, and $p(1)$ is prime, then for $k>0,$ $p(1+kp(1))$ is always divisible by $p(1)$ and greater than $p(1),$ so $p(1+kp(1))$ is composite.

Comment: thank you very much, that is definitely overkill for the problem I am trying to solve :D

Comment: Overkill is my middle name.  @Lantanar

Comment: Seems like a common middle name here @ThomasAndrews

Answer (score 0):

Polynomial remainder theorem is the name of the theorem we use.  It's basic use here, is that it tells us if we shift a variable in a polynomial by a set value, the remainder on division by that value will be the same as the remainder prior to the shift.   That means any polynomial you have $f(n)$ , has $f(h)\mid f(h)\implies f(h)\mid f(f(h)+h)$